# question about this TSQL/XQuery delimiter splitter

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xquery

The below code is a common way of splitting a delimited varchar in TSQL. My question is about
the syntax in the last 2 line. Why are we select N.Value() and giving xml.nodes the alias T(N).

I have not come across this T(N) syntax, i'm unsure what it means and what the N in N.Value is
referencing. I've tried to google this but have found it hard to get an answer, would anyone be
able to help me? Thank you

```
DECLARE @xml as xml,@str as varchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @str='A,B,C,D,E'
SET @delimiter =','
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value 
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
```

Comment: All supported version of SQL Server support `STRING_SPLIT`. Use that instead

Comment: They're just aliases. `T` for the "table" `N` for the column.

Comment: `as T(N)` specifies that the result is a table T with a column N

Comment: Why do you need to specify a column?

Comment: What good is a table with no columns, @Zoories ? And how do you reference said column if it isn't defined? You *are* referencing it in your `SELECT`.

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) "syntaxsql: `nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)`" you need that alias otherwise you can't refer to it.

Comment: I understand now, nodes returns a table

Answer (score 1):

MSFT documentation on XML nodes() Method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15).

The basic syntax of the nodes method is:

```
nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)
```

It transforms the xml data type to relational data, a value per row.

As Panagiotis already pointed out, there is a faster route. If you are using a database with compatibility level of 130 and higher, go can use [the STRING_SPLIT table-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @str as varchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @str='A,B,C,D,E'
SET @delimiter =','
Select [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, @delimiter)
```

Hope this clarifies things for you.